# Retrieve Values from Smoothed Data in FDA/CollocInfer Packages for R

Tags: r

I am using the CollocInfer package, which is heavily dependent on the fda package, in R to estimate the parameters of an ordinary differential equation.  I am able to successfully implement the Generalized Profiling Method to get these parameter estimates, but I cannot figure out how to use the output from the Profile.LS() function to evaluate the estimated solution to the ODE at t0, which will give the estimate of the initial conditions for the ODE based on the data.

**Edit** My previous example was too simple and didn't capture the problem.  Below is the modified example.

**Simple Example** Suppose I have data x, y, which I smooth using a B-spline basis

```
require(fda)
x <- seq(0, 25)
y <- 3 + sin(x) + rnorm(1, 0, 1)
b.basis <- create.bspline.basis(range(x), nbasis=8, norder=4)
smooth.y <- smooth.basis(x, y, b.basis)
yfd <- smooth.y$fd
yfdPar <- fdPar(yfd, 1, 1)
yfd1 <- smooth.fd(yfd, yfdPar)
```

What is the (easiest) way to calculate the value of yfd1 at x=0?

Comment: do you mean this `smooth.y$y[1]`?

Comment: @agstudy Thanks, I made my example too simple.  That command does work for the "fdSmooth" class, but not for the "fd" class, which is the class of yfd1 in the modified code above.  Maybe I need to figure out a way to change "fd" objects to "fdSmooth" or similar objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate a functional data object at specified argument values, using `eval.fd`

```
eval.fd(0,yfd1)
        rep1
[1,] 3.27759
```